# Infinity value error with Linear Regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a pipeline with a pretty basic Linear Regression but I keep running into a value error:
*ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').*

- NaN: i run SimpleImputer in my pipeline and I know my missing values are encoded as NaN
- value too large: my largest value is 200.000 so this should be an issue
- my datatypes are: float64(16), int64(4), uint8(193) (I used get.dummies)

Does this mean "infinity" is the issue? If so, what can I do to fix it?

Can someone suggest what I can do to fix my code or my dataset?

```
#setup the pipeline steps
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.NaN, strategy='most_frequent')), 
         ('reg', LinearRegression())]
          
# Create the pipeline: pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# Fit the pipeline to the training set: 
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the labels of the test set
y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)

print("R^2: {}".format(pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)))
rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Root Mean Squared Error: {}".format(rmse))
```

Comment: I think the order of tuples is relevant. First you scale variables with missing values, that makes no sense.

Comment: @treskov, that is actually a pretty good suggestion. I checked if it worked but it didn't fix the problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What type of variables do you want to include in the model? There can be a problem with scaling - it applies only to quantitative variables. Scaling a categorical variable doesn’t really make much sense. Besides, if you perform OLS with no regularization such as Lasso or Ridge, you don’t need to scale the variables.

Comment: My features are mostly numerical but I did have one categorical feature with country names. I do think this is an important feature, but turning this feature into dummies resulted in a lot of extra columns. I've read quite a bit of Stack Overflow on how to deal with categorical features with a lot of different values in regression, but there doesn't seem to be a simple solution. do you think dropping this column and not using StandardScaler would be a good idea? Or is there a way that I can keep my countries?

Comment: You can keep categorical variables, just don’t perform scaling as it makes no sense for nominal/ordinal variables. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia

Comment: Thank's for your help! I will give it another go :)